# How to set selected values of dynamic dropdowns

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, radio-button, selected

First, I have 3 radio buttons, to choose from one of them.

Next, when you have chosen, you have dependent dynamic dropdowns.

I want when user submit form and there are validation errors, selected value of radio button and  from dropdowns to be shown, not to choose them again.

First, I have to do that for radio buttons named 'role_id'. I've tried to do so for region, but I'm not sure how exactly to do that.

Edited: I made it for radio (ckeck my edited code). But it's difficult for me for dropdowns because I'm new to jQuery. Could you help me? Thanks in advance! :)

I'm using CodeIgniter. My view is:

```js
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $(":radio").click(function(){
                  $('#region').val('Choose region');
                  $('#school').val('Choose region');
                  $('#teacher').val('Choose school');
                  $('#class').val('Choose class');
                  $('#class_divisions').val('Choose division');
              });
          });
         

  

        $(document).ready(function(){
           if($('#radio1').is(':checked') || $('#radio2').is(':checked'))  {

            var dropDown = document.getElementById("region");
            var region = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;

             $('.toggle').show();
             }
          });

         function showHide(self, show){

                  $(".all_teachers_show, .toggle, .school,  .teacher_school, .teacher, .class, .teacher_class").hide();
         
                  if (show)
                      $('.toggle').show();
                  else
                      $('.toggle').hide();
                  $(":radio").prop('checked',false);
                  $(self).prop('checked',true);
              }
              
              function show(yes, no){
                  if (no)
                      $('.school').show();
                  else
                      $('.school').hide();
                  $("region").prop('checked',false);
                  $(yes).prop('checked',true);
              }
          

  

          $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#region').change(function() {
                        var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_schools";
                        var postdata = {region: $('#region').val()};
                        $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                            var $school_sel = $('#school');
                            $school_sel.empty();
                            $school_sel.append("<option>Choose region</option>");
                            var schools_obj = JSON.parse(result);
                            $.each(schools_obj, function(key, val) {
                                var option = '<option  value="' + val.school_id + '" >' + val.school_name + '</option>';
                                $school_sel.append(option);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
```

```html
echo "<tr><td><label>  Choose role:* </label> </td><td>";
  $selected_role = $this->input->post('role_id'); ?>
  <input type="radio" name="role_id" id="radio1" onclick="showHide(this, true)" value="1" 
  <?php echo '1' ==  $selected_role ? 'checked="checked"' : 
      '' ?>/>
      <?php  echo " Ученик "; ?>
      <input type="radio" name="role_id" id="radio2" onclick="showHide(this, true)" value="2" 
  <?php echo '2' ==  $selected_role ? 'checked="checked"' : 
      '' ?>/>
       
      <input type="radio" name="role_id" id="radio5" onclick="teachers_show(this, true)" value="5" 
  <?php echo '5' ==  $selected_role ? 'checked="checked"' : 
      '' ?>/>
  
  
  echo "</td></tr>";
  echo "<tr class='toggle' style='display:none;' ><td><label>  Region*  </label></td><td>";
 
 $selected_region = $this->input->post('region');  ?>
  <select name='region' id='region' onClick='show(this, true)'>
      <?php foreach ($regions as $row) { ?>
        <option name='region' value="<?= $row->region ?>" 
        <?php  echo $row->region ==  $selected_region ? 'selected="selected"' : ''
        ?>>
        <?= $row->region ?></option>
      <?php   } ?>
  </select> 

  
 <?php

  echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr class='school' style='display:none;' ><td><label> School:*  
  </label></td><td>";  
    $selected_school = $this->input->post('school[]');  ?>
<select id="school" name="school[]" class='school' onChange='school_show(this, true)'>
 <option value="" <?php  echo "" ==  $selected_school ? 'selected="selected"' : ''
        ?>>Choose region</option>
  </select>

  
  <?php echo "</td></tr>";
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.school', function(e) {
          alert(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
    
      $( "#school" ).this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text;
     
});
  $('.school').show();      
});
});
```

Comment: could you run the html generated code in the snippet section (its showing the codeigniter code at the moment)

Comment: I changed my code a little, I'll edit my question to show it. Now when radio is clicked and region is clicked and submit form, it is still selected this radio and region. But how to do that for dependent dropdowns after that?

Comment: I'm a little confused with the question - are you trying to make this 'reset' the selections when an error occurs. e.g if user selects a radio box but forgets to make a selection from the dynamic dropdown to then return the page to have both the radio box and dropdown unselected?

Comment: I want when user press Submit button and not all required fields are filled, these fields and dropdowns which he is selected, to be still selected and to have to fill these, that are blank, not to choose again what he has already selected.

Answer (score 0):

To get the form fields to be re-populated you can use the Form Library functionality for this
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>
 <h5>Username</h5>
 <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The **set_value()** will in this form repopulate the value the user has enter in the field (in this case the field named 'username')

As for the retrieving the dropdown which is autogenerated i'd try using the $_POST['region'] value to reproduce the same dropdown again.

e.g in psuedocode

```
if ($_POST array exists) {      
   if ($_POST['region'] has a value) {
     // eg. a region has been previously selected
     retrieve this dropdown using the region parameter 
   }
}
```

Comment: I've done that for username. My problem are dropdowns. See this code: $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#region').change(function() {
                        var url = "<?= base_url() ?>index.php/home/get_schools";
                        var postdata = {region: $('#region').val()};
                        $.post(url, postdata, function(result) {
                            var $school_sel = $('#school');
                            $school_sel.empty();
                            // see  question. From here I tahe region-it is dynamic, that's why I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ok - as the dropdowns are dynamic, have some functionality that will basically pass the region parameter from the $_POST array to the /get_schools function so it knows which 'region' that it should pull into the dropdown menu.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $(document).on('change', '.school', function(e) {
              alert(this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text);
        
          $( "#school" ).this.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text;
         
    });
      $('.school').show();      
    });
    }); This shows me alert with selected option, but how to set that to the school option

Comment: Ok - you can get the value of the selected option?
if so try this..

$('#school').val(yourvalue);

Comment: Yes, but (myvalue) what it should be - how to set selected value there in #school